# How many users can view a public datastudio report at the same time?

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating a report in DataStudio that will use google spreadsheet as data source.
After I publish it as public, how many users can connect and see this report at the  same time?
Is there a quota that may limit the number of access?

Thanks for your help!
Fernando

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit or quota on how many users can view a public Data Studio report at the same time.